# Render text on canvas using WebGL

Tags: text, canvas, rendering, webgl

I want to render some text on a canvas using WebGL, which API of WebGL should be used?

Note: "text" can be either plain text or HTML snippet with CSS style

Answer (score 6):

Most demos that I've seen that do text of any sort (like a FPS counter) simply create an HTML element with the text they want and position it over the canvas. This would probably be a good approach for most text that you would want to show "in" a canvas (ie: menus).

The only exception would be if you want the text to be an actual part of the 3d scene (like, say, text on a billboard), in which case the methodologies wouldn't be any different than rendering text in standard OpenGL. You can find a very good robust example here: http://dmedia.dprogramming.com/?n=Tutorials.TextRendering1

There's also [a WebGL tutorial about text here](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-text-texture.html).

Comment: link is down - server not there

Comment: Please fix the link if you can :)

Comment: Sorry guys, that server was apparently nuked from orbit, and I don't know of any other resources that presented a similar algorithm. :(

Comment: The link appears to be back up (I know this is many months after your requests) - it redirects to http://h3.gd/dmedia/?n=Tutorials.TextRendering1 .

Comment: @Toji: [Here's a mirror](http://fsrv.dyndns.org/mirrors/dmedia-tutorials-textrendering1/index.html) I threw up.

Answer (score 3):

For WebGL-rendered text, you can write text to a canvas "2d" context, then create a texture from the canvas. Denny Koch does that in his EnergizeGL framework.